# Combine Scope and search in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I would like to combine my search result with the scope that user choose.
For instances user search for 'Restaurant' and click 'Toy' link to get a result Restaurant that has toy.

Anyone has any idea how to combine it?

Thanks!

Model

```
scope :filter_by_toy, -> { where(toy: true) }
scope :filter_by_play_area, -> { where(play_area: true) }
```

Controller

```
def index
  @places = policy_scope(Place)
  @places = Place.all
  @places = Place.global_search(params[:query]) unless params[:query].blank?

  #scope filtering
  if params[:toy]
    @places = @places.filter_by_toy
  end

if params[:play_area]
    @places = @places.filter_by_play_area
  end
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for :search, url: places_path, class: "search-form", method: :get do %>
  <div class="search-box">
      <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query],
        class: "search-input placeholder-search",
        placeholder: "City, place name, type..."%>
      <button type="submit" class="search-submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Toy', places_path(:toy => true) %>
<%= link_to 'Play Area', places_path(:play_area => true) %>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? Looks alright to me. Edit: Oh, you mean combine the query on the view, not the results on the controller. I see.

Comment: Which library do you use for searching?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to include all the filters (links) as options of a select box on the form, instead of using separate links? You UI is not making much sense to me.

Comment: @ChristianBruckmayer I use pg_search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, forms work like this: you click "submit" and all the values within the form (from inputs, checkboxes, etc) are sent in one batch to the server. You can read more about forms here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Specifically for your problem, you could replace your links with checkboxes using `check_box_tag` and move them inside the form. See more: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag

```
<%= form_for :search, url: places_path, class: "search-form", method: :get do %>
  <div class="search-box">
      <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query],
        class: "search-input placeholder-search",
        placeholder: "City, place name, type..."%>
      <%= check_box_tag "toy" %>
      <%= check_box_tag "play_area" %>
      <button type="submit" class="search-submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```